# How to iterate results in hits array and post data to elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Scenario: I need to query elasticsearch by defining Monitors in Kibana Alerting feature and post results to another elasticsearch by using custom webhook.

Steps: Defined a Monitor using Extraction query editor with search phrase and got results array.

```
{
"_shards": {
    "total": 28,
    "failed": 0,
    "successful": 28,
    "skipped": 0
},
"hits": {
    "hits": [
        {
            "_index": "logs-2022.05.09",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_source": {
                "msg": "out of memory",
                "app_name": "abc",
                "@timestamp": "2022-05-09T07:11:29.371Z"
            },
            "_id": "o96op4ABzvU99XCLyUbl",
            "_score": 0
        },
        {
            "_index": "logs-2022.05.09",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_source": {
                "msg": "out of memory ",
                "app_name": "12345",
                "@timestamp": "2022-05-09T07:19:37.848Z"
            },
            "_id": "-yiwp4ABkpBQgqcxMG-e",
            "_score": 0
        },
        {
            "_index": "logs-cfsyslog-2022.05.09",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_source": {
                "msg": "out of memory ",
                "app_name": "45678",
                "@timestamp": "2022-05-09T15:33:45.240Z"
            },
            "_id": "-g90qYABzvU99XCLkuDf",
            "_score": 0
        }
    ],
    "total": {
        "value": 3,
        "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 0
},
"took": 4758,
"timed_out": false
```

}

Trigger condition in Kibana UI:
ctx.results[0].hits.total.value > 0

Defined Actions in Kibana UI:
selected custom webhook (defined elasticsearch url & credentials)

```
{
"msg": "{{ctx.results[0].hits.hits[0]._source.msg}}",
"app_name": "{{ ctx.results[0].hits.hits[0]._source.app_name}}",
"time": "{{ctx.results.hits.hits.0._source.@timestamp}}"
}
```

Query:
How can i repeat all the values from hits array and make a call to post the data to elasticsearch for every result in hits array. currently i am able to post only first result. Kindly advise how to proceed with this scearion